# Dynamic Avatar using Material UI and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I have a basic form validation app. Build in react.js. Each user is assigned a profile, with his information. I want to use the first letter of his name, let's say `Peter`, the `P`, and display it to an avatar, with the letter p and a random color.

React-Material-UI has an example but I am afraid it is only for static avatars. I want it to be dynamic.

Requirements

```
Given that a user has a first name
And he is logged in
Then he should see a round random colored letter with his first name.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you passed your component some `user` that is an object with an attribute `firstName` so that you can do something like `user.firstName` you could do something like this:

```
<Avatar className={classes.avatar}>{user.firstName.charAt(0)}</Avatar>
```

Where `classes.avatar` is taken from the Material-UI example that you referenced above.

Comment: i have a question. I did everything the documentation said, and you. But it throws an error `UserView.js?32c9:289 Uncaught ReferenceError: classes is not defined`. The code I used is here:

                                ```avatar= {<Avatar className={classes.avatar}>{this.props.data.username.charAt(0)}</Avatar>}``` . THe prop is that. I am sure. It is used multple times elsewhere in the app, no problems. SO what is goind on?

Comment: In the docs, there is a `styles` object defined above the `function LetterAvatars(props)` definition and then there is `const { classes } = props` right below that at the first line of the function.  At the bottom of that code snippet, there is `export default withStyles(styles)(LetterAvatars);` which exports the component as a "Higher Order Component" and automatically injects it with the `prop` called `classes` which is why that occurs above in the first line of the function.  If you do the same as that snippet (or just get rid `className={classes.avatar}` the error will disappear.